# How to prove uniqueness or non uniqueness of nonlinear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$uu_x+u_y=-3u$ is the nonlinear PDE we are looking at and there are some initial condition given for example $u(x,3x)=x^2$. How to decide there is a unique solution or many solution or no solution?

There are two ways I tried to prove uniqueness. One way is before formation of singularity, the solution can be achieved by method of characteristics. But for the place where characteristics intersect, I don't know how to locate these singularity and what are the values in the intersection of characteristics?

Another way is by estimation, but due to nonlinear, I find it is hard for me to give estimate for the first nonlinear term. Energy estimation kind of get stuck.

Comment: Having edited the ways I tried

Comment: Try with the energy $E(y) = \int u^2\,\text d x>0$. It may be decreasing with $y$.